# WPF Access the DataContext in a CustomMarkup for DataTrigger Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a custom MarkupExtension to create a binding for my ViewModel, because i have to call a method to get a object and create a binding to a property of the returned object.

This works good so far for control property bindings like TextBox.Text etc

I want to use the same behavior for a DataTrigger Binding but it doesn't work because my MarkupExtension gets called with the DataTrigger as TargetObject and it doesn't have a DataContext.

Is there any way to get access to my DataContext (ViewModel) in this case?

As a workaround i tried to use a custom ValueConverter and use the DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" to pass the DataContext (ViewModel) to the converter and the converter returns the Property Value, this works for the first call but it doesn't update if the Property Value changes, because the actuall binding is to the ViewModel (which doesn't change) so that didn't work either.

```
// Example
public class ExampleMarkup : MarkupExtension
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var targetProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;

        // For bindings on normal controls/properties (for example TextBox.Text) this returns the FrameworkElement
        var element = targetProvider.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;

        var viewModel = element.DataContext as ViewModel;
        var property = viewModel.GetProperty(PropertyName);

        // But for a DataTrigger Binding the TargetObject is the DataTrigger which does not have a DataContext 
        // How can i get access to my model to call the GetProperty method?

        // ... other code ...

        // ... create a binding for the property instance and return it ...
    }
}

public class Property : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ... other code ...

    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // ... other code ...
}

public class ViewModel
{
    // ... other code ...

    // Returns the property instance
    public Property GetProperty(string id)
    {
        // ... code to find/return the property ...
    }

    // ... other code ...
}
```

Comment: You can create a multibinding converter and paas both the viewmodel and the propertyvalue

Comment: Im not sure if i understand your comment correctly, but if i pass the viewmodel and the propertyvalue (i could only pass the name) to the multibinding with a converter which gets the property value from the viewmodel, it works for the first time but it doesn't get updated if the property value changes
I assume this is because the binding is not directly between the property instance and it doesn't listen to the property changed events